# What are the licensing concerns running Mac OS X guest OS on VMWare ESXi 5.5 with non-apple hardware?

Tags: macos, mac, vmware

How do I install Mac OS X as a guest OS on VMWare ESXi 5.5 Update 1 running on non apple hardware?

We currently have a large deployment of HP server hardware running VMWare ESXi 5.5 Update 1. We have numerous Windows and Linux deployments in this environment and all works very well. Now we are in need of a virtual install of Mac OS X. We don't want to hack it in and we don't want to violate any EULA's, we just want virtual Mac OS X in our environment. Does this mean we need new hardware in the data center to support this?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running OS X on unsupported hardware.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is installing Mavericks on Hackintosh legal?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/107324/is-installing-mavericks-on-hackintosh-legal)

Comment: Let's keep this open if possible. We can certainly be a place for people to explain what the EULA is, how it might apply and whether it's even technically possible. If we end up down a rabbit hole of how to configure ESX in a way that's exclusively PC based, perhaps we might migrate it to SU, but this seems a reasonable question for a professional to ask / answer and still be within our scope. A discussion on [meta] would be great if people have strong feelings about closure or we want to discuss how to edit it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't run OS X virtualized or not, on non-Apple-branded hardware per the software license agreement.  You would need Apple hardware to virtualize it and be compliant with the EULA.

[Mavericks EULA](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX109.pdf)

Comment: So you think it´s legal to install ESXi on a Mac mini and install a few VMs with Mavericks?!

Comment: Yes, see http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/apple